# Trace source file of an error_log php

Tags: php, error-log

I often use error_log to output information when I am developing stuff so I can see the content of arrays and such- I am not sure if this is a good way of doing things but I am self taught so forgive me!

Anyway, somewhere I must have forgotten to comment an error_log out because I am continuously getting an error_log message of 'post_type=' and for the life of me I just cannot track it down, I have done a search for 'post_type=' in all of my files and also been through every error_log I can find and checked that it is commented out but just cannot track this darn thing down...

SO what I was wondering is if anyone knows how I can trace the source of the last error_logged message so I can find the file that is sending it. I tried error_get_last() but this isn't returning anything I think because its not actually an error that is getting logged but a message I am outputting manually...

Failing that, I see that in Dreamweaver  there is a way to search using regular expressions and was just wondering if anyone knows how I can make it search for error_log that not preceded by '//'

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you using a `syslog` a custom one, or something else?

Comment: For the future, always use at least: `__FILE_` when outputting messages (i normally add: `.__LINE__`). File search: 'agent ransack' on 'windows' is an excellent free 'file search' utility.

Comment: Good tip there Ryan thankyou

Comment: @robbmj I'm not sure I havent set anything up, just using php's error_log() to do it...

Comment: @robbmj looking into it a bit more I found out what syslog is and no its not using that its just outputting to a error_log file

Comment: @DavidO'Sullivan If you post your logging implementation I might be able to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your error log file permissions to nothing, so only "root" user has access to it.
Then navigate on your website, and hopefully at some point you'll trigger that error, and as Apache won't have the rights to write in this file, php will trigger an error, giving you the opportunity to know from where it comes.

Also, if you are willing to see the content of a variable, you can use `var_dump($myVar)`.

Comment: Ok sounds interesting, so CHMOD the file permissions from 644 to 0, then where will php trigger the error? Or will the site not load but show the error message?

Comment: Ok I think I tried what you suggested but couldn't seem to get any obvious error message- all that seems to happen is that there are no new messages added to the errorlog file- though as I say above I'm not sure where I should look for the error you say php should be triggering...

Comment: you also must configure php to show errors. add : error_reporting(E_ALL); to your index.php file (assuming you are using a single entry point to your application).